# A very unexpected downvote

Tags: support, downvoting

Someone has just downvoted my question and answer for this question:

[Dynamic number of columns in a pageBlockTable](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/245/80)

I can only assume this is some sort of retributive voting, as this is the highest voted question and answer I have posted on this site.

What should I do in a situation like this?

Comment: I noticed that one of my answers, with 10+ score, just got downvoted, too. Maybe we have a rogue contrarian ;- )

Comment: how curious :) Behavior like that really baffles me. I took a leaf out of eyescream's book and upvoted your answer

Comment: I noticed exactly the same yesterday too. ( http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/652/call-javascript-function-from-your-apex-method/653#653 ) Maybe someone is going through old answers downvoting things for "fun".

Comment: Can moderators review downvotes or can we have a feature where answers with upvotes of 5 or above cannot be downvoted without giving an explanation for the same?

Comment: I would post this as a question in meta and the Stack Exchange mods will respond

Answer (score 6):

Don't think you can do much.

I doubt it's Stephen's "retribution" as

1. Looks like you've sorted out the pros & cons of approach in the comments to his answer
2. His profile says he has 0 downvotes.

Might be somebody else you've been commenting / voting with recently...

I'd say ignore it? If they didn't bother to leave a comment or not-really-an-answer "doesn't work for me!", what else can you do about it? it's only -4 in reputation after all.

It's a good question and very kind of you to come back and answer it yourself with something that's useful for more people. I've just voted myself ;)

Comment: Most appreciated, I now have a net positive out of it :) I didn't for a second think it was Stephen either

Comment: Pretty much impossible to say what it was or why — there are some systems that monitor serial downvotes I think, but otherwise there's no way to find out who voted.